# Where to add margin on the original price?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, import, catalog-price-rules

I have the problem that the imported prices are the prices from the wholesale and my buying price.

However I'd like to add a margin based on the price ranges and sell it accordingly.

The rules are easy:

- 0-500: 15%
- 500-1000: 18%
- 1000-1500: 20%
- etc.

Is there any standard? I used to work with the plugin Percentage Pricing but unfortunately there are side effects like on special price it doesn't work. It seems that also the "promotion"-setting could set the same pricing as percentage pricing does.

So I'd like to stick as much as possible to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The standard would be to use tier prices, but those work on product level. If there's any chance to preprocess the import files, I would do this, and calculate the tier prices before importing them.

For the default Import/Export CSV format, tier prices can be imported like this:

[image: tier price csv]

**Source:** https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/